# How can Weierstrass product for the gamma function reduce to Wallis formula for $\pi$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, gamma-function, pi, infinite-product

According to the Wikipedia article about Pi, if we set $z=\frac{1}{2}$ to
$$\Gamma (z)=\dfrac{e^{-\gamma z}}{z}\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{z/n}}{1+z/n}$$
and square the result, we get the Wallis product for $\pi$.

In my attempt, I ended up with
$$\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{4n^2e^{1/n}}{(2n+1)^2}=\dfrac{\pi e^\gamma}{4},$$
but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n-\ln n\right)$$
and so
$$e^{\gamma}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^1e^{1/2}\cdots e^{1/n}}n.$$
Thus
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{4n^2e^{1/n}}{(2n+1)^2}
=e^{\gamma}\lim_{N\to\infty}N\prod_{n=1}^N \frac{(2n)^2}{(2n+1)^2}
=\frac{e^\gamma}2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac21\frac23\frac43\cdots
\frac{2N}{2N-1}\frac{2N}{2N+1}$$
which looks a bit more like the Wallis product.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. But how do I get rid of the factor of $\frac{e^\gamma}{2}$?

Comment: That Wallis product should equal $\pi/2$ surely? @Kaju

Comment: If $e^\gamma/2 \times \text{product} = \pi e^\gamma/4$, then...

Comment: How do I show that $\lim_{N\to\infty}N\prod_{n=1}^N \frac{4n^2}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}$?